# how to get this frame's name in my javascript code 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

this is my html code :

```
<frameset rows="18,*" frameborder=0 framespacing=0>
    <frame src="/zh-cn/MapS/MainTop/" noresize scrolling=no>
   <frameset cols="0,*,210" name="menu">
     <frame src="/zh-cn/MapS/MainLeft/" scrolling=no noresize>
     <frame src="/zh-cn/MapS/Watch/" name="desk">
     <frame src="/zh-cn/MapS/RightMenu/" scrolling=no noresize>
    </frameset>
  </frameset>
```

and this is the javascript code in on frame :

```
parent.parent.frames[2].frames[0]
```

i want to know which name is this frame ,

i do this :

```
console.log(parent.parent.frames[2].frames[0].nodename)
```

it show:

```
undefined
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the src value.

```
console.log(parent.parent.frames[2].frames[0].location.href)
```

Comment: Again a wrong answer is marked as the correct answer. This gives the Url, not the name!

Answer (score 6):

For example, this should work

```
window.frameElement.name
```

Also, if all you have is a reference to an element inside a frame and want to know the frame name this element belongs to:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].ownerDocument.defaultView.window.frameElement.name
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are all the answers here so complicated ?

The name of the current document (== frame name) can be obtained via:

```
var sName = window.name;
```

If the current document is the root document or if the parent document has not assigned a name to the child frame, sName will be an empty string.

Comment: window.frameElement won't work with CORS. but window.name inside will be set to the same value as on the iframe

Comment: The question was how to get "this frame's name". So CORS is not a topic here. window.name will work always inside the same frame.

Comment: @Elmue ... not necessarily assuming one has control over some/all CORS domains/script ends

Answer (score 1):

Greetings,

You can create a function to retrieve the frame element name from within the frame content like that:

```
function getFrameName(frame) {
    var frames = parent.frames, 
        l = frames.length, 
        name = null;

    for (var x=0; x<l; x++) {
        if (frames[x] === frame) {
            name = frames[x].name;
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

And then call it inside the document:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
        name = getFrameName(self);

    if (name != null) {
        var text = document.createTextNode("this frame name is: " + name);

        body.appendChild(text);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<html>
<frameset  rows="18,*">
    <frame name="MainTop" src="/zh-cn/MapS/MainTop/" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
    <frameset  cols="0,*,210">
        <frame name="MainLeft" src="/zh-cn/MapS/MainLeft/" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
        <frame name="Watch" src="/zh-cn/MapS/Watch/" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
        <frame name="RightMenu" src="/zh-cn/MapS/RightMenu/" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Test Script:

```
console.log(parent.frames[2].name);
```

Comment: By following the DOM you'll see that MainTop is 0, MainLeft is 1, Watch is 2 and RightMenu is 3. Based on the actual modeling of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Why all that trouble?
Just

`frames.name`

gives you the current frame name.

Answer (score 0):

Current page:

**`location.pathname`**

Current page's address:

**`location.href`**

First frame inside the page:

**`parent.frames[0].name`**

note that:

```
window.document.location
```